# Why can't I sign in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I reset my password and tried to log in, it won't log in. It is just saying invalid username or password.

Answer (score 1):

This really is only answerable when we know whether you have migrated your Mojang account or not. If you have, use your email instead of your username.

**After resetting your password you may be forced to wait 30 minutes to 24 h hours before you can successfully sign in, as seen [here.](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/781529-login-failed)**

This is most likely what is happening to you, I have personally encountered this before. If you have not already, make sure to take time to migrate your Mojang account, [as it will be required for future Minecraft updates.](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/775905-migrating-from-minecraft-to-mojang)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer could be made better with a source.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have migrated to a mojang account so use your email instead of your IGN.Or just contact them at [their website](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new). If its not working try changing your username or pass so it might work again.